# SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration manager throws "Invalid Class" message

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have re-installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine and I also have SQL Server 2014 installed on the same machine. After re-installing SQL Server 2008 R2, I don't get Report Service Instance name and when I click "Find", it throws "Invalid Class". Please refer to attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Thanks.
Vishal

Comment: could you show the screenshot of error message also?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well guys I have uninstalled SQL Server 200 R2 and all its components. Re Installed and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

check there are ssrs databases.check database data and status.Database is not available then try uninstall ssrs and install again.